# Its just the main function of spring boot application

Tags: intellij-idea, java-17, spring-boot-maven-plugin

Errors in IntelliJ application using java

I'm trying to use spring initializer to build a maven project and it cannot resolve symbol 'String'

Comment: Do you have an SDK defined?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.